# MySQL Left join take too long for huge data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables .Property tables and it related photo.One property may have many photo but I want only one any of it related photo, When I use left join MySQL query it become too slow.

Here is my query

```
SELECT `sp_property`.`id` as propertyid, `sp_property`.`property_name`, `sp_property`.`property_price`, `sp_property`.`adv_type`, `sp_property`.`usd`, `images`.`filepath_name` 
FROM (`sp_property`) 
LEFT JOIN  (select id, Max(property_id) as pid,filepath_name 
            from sp_property_images
            group by property_id) `images`
ON `images`.`pid` = `sp_property`.`id` 
WHERE `sp_property`.`published` = 'yes' 
GROUP BY `propertyid` 
ORDER BY `sp_property`.`feature_listing` desc, `submit_date` desc
LIMIT 1,20



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sp_property_images` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `filepath_name` text,
  `label_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primary` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `property_id` (`property_id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12941 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sp_property` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `propertytype` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `adv_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `property_name` text,
  `division` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `township` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `property_price` decimal(20,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `availability` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_address` text,
  `p_dimension_length` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `p_dimension_width` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `p_dimension_sqft` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `p_dimension_acre` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `floor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aircorn` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ownership` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `bedroom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `bathroom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `special_feature` text,
  `amentites` text,
  `property_detail` text,
  `submit_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `published` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `published_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `agent_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `contact_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact_no` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `contact_address` text NOT NULL,
  `contact_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `unit_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_lat` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `map_long` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `show_map` varchar(3) DEFAULT 'no',
  `total_view` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `feature_listing` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `new_homes_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `publish_price` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `usd` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18524 ;
```

Comment: Please show us the schemas of your tables.

Comment: Are you want to view my table structure and data?

Comment: Yes, in particular your table structure including all column types and index definitions.

Comment: if you don't mind I could send you these two table for testing by mail bez
i don't know how to show on this page

Comment: Simply put the SQL statements to create the tables and the indexes into a code block.

Comment: @khittl I was edited my post with actual tables. Please look it. Two table will connect by property_id . All the logic is same :) .

Comment: Which columns do you use to join your tables? `sp_property_images.property_id` is a `varchar(100)` which seems off. Shouldn't that be an int (the same type as your `id` PK column in the other table)

Comment: I used sp_property id for foreign  key

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please update your query to match your table definitions?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? It takes seconds? How long is it taking?

Comment: An explain plan could help identifying the problem. The right part of your join is kind of wierd tho group and max on property_id.

Comment: @Ryan it take around 3 min for 15000 records

Comment: That does seem slow. Is that 15000 to get the `resultset` or is that the size of the tables? Whatever, it is slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added indices on your tables? You would need three indices on the following columns:

- article_photo.a_id for grouping and joining
- article_photo.p_id for sorting
- article.a_id for joining (although this is hopefully already the PK of your table)

The result of joins is not guaranteed to be sorted in any order, so you probably want to move your `ORDER BY` clause from the subquery to the outer query:

```
 SELECT * from `article` 
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT * from `article_photo`  
 GROUP BY `a_id`) as images 
 ON article.a_id = images.a_id
 ORDER BY images.p_id DESC
```

Also, you have no guarantee on which article_photo you will get, since select data without an aggregate function (and only MySQL will allow you to do that).

---

Now that the question contains the real tables and all information essential to answering, here's my take – first, here's your query:

```
SELECT `sp_property`.`id` as propertyid, `sp_property`.`property_name`, `sp_property`.`property_price`, `sp_property`.`adv_type`, `sp_property`.`usd`, `images`.`filepath_name` 
FROM (`sp_property`) 
LEFT JOIN  (select id, Max(property_id) as pid,filepath_name 
            from sp_property_images
            group by property_id) `images`
ON `images`.`pid` = `sp_property`.`id` 
WHERE `sp_property`.`published` = 'yes' 
GROUP BY `propertyid` 
ORDER BY `sp_property`.`feature_listing` desc, `submit_date` desc
LIMIT 1,20
```

Let's see. you are joining `sp_property_images.property_id` with `sp_property.id`. These columns have different types (`int` vs. `varchar`) and I suppose this results in a severe performance penalty (since the values have to be converted to the same type).

Then, you are filtering by `sp_property.published`, so I suggest adding an index on this column as well. Also, examine if you really need to have this column as varchar. A bool/bit flag probably suffices as well (if it doesn't, an enum might be a better choice still).

Ordering benefits from an index too. Add an index spanning *both* columns `sp_property.feature_listing` and `sp_property.submit_date`.

If all of the above still doesn't help, you might have to remove the sub-select. It might prevent the mysql engine from recognizing (and using!) the index you have defined on the `sp_property_images.property_id` column.

Comment: no problem for article photo. But it still slow @knittl

Comment: @Nay: have you added indexes on all columns I have mentioned in my answer? Shouldn't be slow, especially not with only 10 k rows.

Comment: Yes I have been added but it still slow. By the way I use MyISAM engine

Comment: @Nay: shouldn't be. Have you created three separate indexes? Please show us the schema of your tables.

Comment: Your are great.Now I added index to cols and remove sub select.It is work :-)

Answer (score 0):

This simple query will give you what you asked for, all articles with their photos

```
SELECT ar.a_id, ar.a_title, ap.p_id, ap.photo_name 
FROM article ar
JOIN article_photo ap on ar.a_id = ap.a_id
```

No reason for left join and grouping there or you wanna get sum on photos by article?

Comment: Google about indexes and drop indexes on your article table and article_photo table ... it will speed it up